# Sass error: Can't find stylesheet to import when importing bootstrap

Tags: css, import, sass, bootstrap-5

I am trying to add bootstrap to my directory using npm.
This is my file structure:

[image]

I am using @import in my style.scss file

```
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

And my package.json looks like this. It's basically starter kid from this site -
[minimum-static-site-sass-setup](https://thinkdobecreate.com/articles/minimum-static-site-sass-setup/)

```
{
"name": "playground",
"version": "0.1.0",
"description": "SASS compile|autoprefix|minimize and live-reload dev server using Browsersync for static HTML",
"main": "public/index.html",
"author": "5t3ph",
"scripts": {
    "build:sass": "sass  --no-source-map src/sass:public/css",
    "copy:assets": "copyfiles -u 1 ./src/assets/**/* public",
    "copy:html": "copyfiles -u 1 ./src/*.html public",
    "copy": "npm-run-all --parallel copy:*",
    "watch:assets": "onchange \"/src/assets/**/*\" -- npm run copy:html",
    "watch:html": "onchange \"src/*.html\" -- npm run copy:html",
    "watch:sass": "sass  --no-source-map --watch src/sass/:public/css",
    "watch": "npm-run-all --parallel watch:*",
    "serve": "browser-sync start --server public --files public",
    "start": "npm-run-all copy --parallel watch serve",
    "build": "npm-run-all copy:html build:*",
    "postbuild": "postcss public/css/*.css -u autoprefixer cssnano -r --no-map"
},
"dependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.2",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "browser-sync": "^2.27.7",
    "copyfiles": "^2.4.1",
    "cssnano": "^5.0.17",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "onchange": "^7.1.0",
    "postcss-cli": "^9.1.0",
    "sass": "^1.49.8"
}
```

}

Every time I try to compile it, I get this error:

```
"Error: Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
6 │ @import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
  │         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  src\sass\style.scss 6:9  root stylesheet"
```

I tried many potential solutions from stackoverflow but none of them seems to work for me.

Any idea, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I tried putting it in my base style folder, changing route but every time I run into same problem...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

wrong path, that was the problem :)

Comment: I don't know why, usually ```@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";``` works, but this time I had to switch to ```@import "~node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";```. Also don't forget to include the Bootstrap JavaScript in the script parts of ```angular.json```.

Comment: @MikhailRatner, I'm also facing the same error i.e., generally `@use "@angular/material" as mat;` should work but I have to do `@use "node_modules/@angular/material" as mat;` . Have you found the answer why the packages are not directly available to scss files?

Comment: Hi @Ravi , sorry I did not find an answer for that.

Answer (score 4):

Open the `angualr.json` and find the `options` object then add `stylePreprocessorOptions`(**The Path is** `Projects-> Your Project Name-> architect-> build-> options`). as follows:

```
"options": {
         ...
  "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
     "includePaths": [
         "node_modules/",
         "src/assets" // I place my *.csss here . You can add your path
      ]
   },
}
```

Comment: After this use:
@import "compass-sass-mixins/lib/compass";

Answer (score 1):

You can try with:

**@import "~node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";**

or

**@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";**

Comment: unfortunately, same error :/

Comment: I don't know why, usually ```@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";``` works, but this time I had to switch to ```@import "~node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";```. Also don't forget to include the Bootstrap JavaScript in the script parts of ```angular.json```.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add this part in my angular.json after updating to Angular 15
(under build options):

```
        "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
          "includePaths": [
            "node_modules"
          ]
        },
```

[image]

Also for some bizare reason I had to change my import in styles.scss to

```
@import '../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

instead of

```
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

Answer (score -3):

don't you need a .css or something like that in the end? Shouldn't an extension be there?